# How to get relative path in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, relative-path, filereader, absolute-path

I am trying to include the file testrules.drl in my Java code but it keeps giving me a NullPointerException. Am I declaring the relative path correctly? I tried it with the absolute path but I still get the same error....

```
private static String DRL_FILE = "/src/main/resources/rules/testrules.drl";
...
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(Main.class.getResourceAsStream(DRL_FILE)); //this gives a NullPointeException
```

Below is the image:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace for us to look at?

Comment: @RomanVottner - Roman Vottner is right!! I don't need to specify /src/main/resources. The /rules/filename.drl works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try just using this

```
new InputStreamReader("src/main/resources/rules/testrules.drl");
```